# Ubuntu 16.10 installed under UEFI mode, now can't boot into Windows 10 or Ubuntu, getting grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

After reading around on the internet and even trying the ubuntu forums, I've decided to come here for help.  Here's some information that may be useful:

My partitions are as follows (as seen from the Ubuntu installation):

```
/dev/sda ATA ST31000524AS (1.0 TB)
/dev/sda1 ntfs 104MB 29MB used Windows 7 (loader)
/dev/sda2 ntfs 912682 unknown used Windows 7 (loader)
/dev/sda4 ext4 / 79224MB Ubuntu
/dev/sda3 swap 8191MB unknown used

/dev/sdb  ATA SAMSUNG HD 103SI (1.0TB)
/dev/sdb1 ntfs 1000202MB unknown used Windows 10 (loader)
```

Previously, this machine had Windows 7 installed on it.  At that time, an external hard drive of mine had some of its hardware broken, so I pulled the drive out and stuck it in my machine as an internal drive.  I *think* that is what /dev/sdb is.  Shortly after that, I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and successfully had Ubuntu 15.10 running alongside it.

Recently, I have tried to install Ubuntu 16.10 via USB.  The USB was in UEFI mode, although my BIOS is set to Legacy (so I can boot into Windows 10).  After I did that, I was being sent to the grub rescue screen.  An ls at the grub rescue screen yields:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,mosdos4) (hd1,msdos3) (hd1,msdos2) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2) (hd2,msdos1).

ls (hd1,msdos4)
(hd1,msdos4): Filesystem is ext2
```

I have tried the instructions here: [redacted due to lack of reputation/can't post more than 2 links]

> 1. set prefix=(hdX,Y)/boot/grub
>      Use the values determined earlier. Example: If the Ubuntu system is on sda5, >enter: set prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub
>      2.* set root=(hdX,Y)
>      Example: set root=(hd0,5)
> 2. insmod normal
>      Attempt to load the normal module.
> 3. normal
>      Activate the normal module. If successful, the GRUB 2 menu may appear.
> 4. set
>      (Optional) Review the current settings.
> 5. ls /boot
>      (Optional) Check for a vmlinuz and a initrd.img entry.
> 6. insmod linux
>      An error message usually means the path is incorrect.
>      8.* linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdXY ro
>      Selects the latest kernel. Example: linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro
> 7. initrd /initrd.img
>      Selects the latest initrd image.
> 8. boot

At some point, I also tried some e2fsck commands, https://pastebin.com/SM2fMXHr

I have just now tried to run a boot repair, and here are the results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24282296/

After all that, my question is:

What should I do to be able to boot into Ubuntu and Windows 10?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done an EFI-mode installation; it looks like it's BIOS-mode, but with GRUB (somewhat strangely) installed to `/dev/sdb`. It looks like Ubuntu was meant to be installed to `/dev/sda4`, but that partition is showing bad filesystem damage. I recommend you try re-installing Ubuntu, but you may want to read [my page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) first, to help you control the boot mode. Also, be sure to create a fresh filesystem on ("reformat") `/dev/sda4` when you install.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The only time I have seen machines with both you have to choose at boot. On a cold start what F-Keys are offered? Most have a bios and a boot choice. Mine is F-12. Have a live CD? Boot that and choose test Ubuntu. The next restart do it again and choose HD. then the boot screen will show the choices to boot Ubuntu or a Windows 7 or 10.